# Masmorra conversion cards

Tags: arcadia-quest

I know in the Kickstarter for Masmorra there was a stretch goal (met) that provided cards to convert Masmorra heroes to be playable in Arcadia Quest.  I was at CMON Expo recently and obtained several Masmorra hero minis, but not the actual game (I didn't like Masmorra very much) so now I'm trying to find where, if at all, the conversion cards are available for download (legally, of course) or purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image, found on Google image search, from an eBay listing, has the stats and abilities of the 5 base Masmorra heroes. https://goo.gl/images/sk59WV

Answer (score 1):

The stretch goal which provided Arcadia Quest cards for all of the bonus minis was listed as a Kickstarter exclusive goal, so I strongly doubt you will ever find the cards for sale except via someone selling them on eBay or a similar site.

Otherwise the Masmorra base game box does include Arcadia Quest cards for the five heroes it contains.

Comment: Good to know they are exclusive. I found an image that has the info I'm looking for online but am disappointed I can't buy them.